# how to request multiple values from same key using eve

Tags: python, json, mongodb, eve

I have an eve app running on my mongodb collection `col10`. I am trying to get a response where I have multiple values selected from the same key, example:

```
http://127.0.0.1:4567/col10?where={"var0053":[1130,1113]}
## returns 0 objects
```

I have also tried:

```
http://127.0.0.1:4567/col10?where=var0053==[1130,1113] 
## returns just the objects with var0053 = 1113
```

is there a way of requesting to server more than one value from the same key?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using GET method your url should be looking like that :

```
 http://IP_ADDRESS:8080/test?list=1&list=2&list=3
```

for retrieving it:

```
String[] arrlist=request.getParameterValues('list');
```

your array will be filled with separated values:

```
//["1","2","3"]
```

When you retrieving your list parameters it wouldn't be parsed as array but as a **series of String**  which will be grouped later on into an array.
Which means even if you write it `list[]=1&list[]=2&list[]=3`, `list[=1&list[=2&list[=3`, `list*=1&list*=2&list*=3` or `list=1&list=2&list=3` it would always be giving you the same answer whether you retrieve it as

```
request.getParameterValues('list[]') //["1","2","3"]
request.getParameterValues('list[') //["1","2","3"]
request.getParameterValues('list*') //["1","2","3"]
request.getParameterValues('list')  //["1","2","3"]
```

Answer (score 1):

With Eve, you can use `mongodb` syntax for queries, like this:

`http://127.0.0.1:4567/col10?where={"var0053": {"$in": ["1130", "1113"]}}`

Documentation is here https://docs.python-eve.org/en/stable/features.html#filtering.